# MVC 3.0 : why no client-side validation messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a model like this

```
public class SampleModel{
   public int No{get;set;} 
}
```

and in view I have a custom ValidationFor which shows a star near the inputbox for this field :

```
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.No)
        @Html.ValidationMessageWithStarFor(model => model.No)
```

So in rendering I have a "*" nears the inputbox which tells the field is required. It works in server-side properly but it doesn't work in client-side.
In spite of Enabling ClientValidation in web.confing through these lines :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
```

...how can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to reference the following scripts in your page in addition to jQuery:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No! i've these two lines :
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Mahmoud Moravej, then probably your custom validation helper doesn't generate the proper HTML5 data-* attributes on the DOM elements. Make sure that it generates the same markup as the standard `ValidationMessageFor` helper. Even better try the standard ValidationMessageFor helper to see if it works.

Comment: using ValidationMessageFor has the same result! :-(

Answer (score 0):

the problem was because of the following code :

```
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

which prevents dataannotation to validate not nullable types.

Comment: Where did you change that line?

Comment: @Serge It should be in global.ascx.cs file. If it doesn't exist there, add it yourself